# Panning in future dated xAxis Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to make the panning functionality to pan on future dated xAxis?

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
            }
        }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
  });
});
```

Please refer to this test file I created http://jsfiddle.net/bxg57pav/
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you mean by panning on future dated xAxis?

Comment: what I meant was to be able to scroll from right to left of chart (panning) even without data on the date of xAxis